# Postfix mail boundes due to dynamic IP

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail, dynamic-ip

I am attempting to set up a send-only mail server on my ubuntu machine to send emails to one of my email accounts to notify me of jobs finishing.

I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

I have attempted to send a few mails, and errors similar to these appear in my log file: `/var/log/mail.log`

```
43 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/smtp[15897]: 25F0C1208C0: to=<myemail@live.co.uk>, orig_to=<root@hostname>, relay=mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.33.135]:25, delay=2.4, delays=0.03/0/2.2/0.16, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.33.135] said: 550     DY-001 (COL004-MC6F29) Unfortunately, messages from 80.7.239.61 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider. You can tell them that Hotmail does not relay dynamically-assigned IP ranges. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/trou    bleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
44 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/smtp[15897]: 25F0C1208C0: lost connection with mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.33.135] while sending RCPT TO
45 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/cleanup[15895]: 8E5171208C2: message-id=<20160709005038.8E5171208C2@hostname>
46 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/bounce[15902]: 25F0C1208C0: sender non-delivery notification: 8E5171208C2
47 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/qmgr[15890]: 8E5171208C2: from=<>, size=2986, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
48 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/qmgr[15890]: 25F0C1208C0: removed
49 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/local[15978]: 8E5171208C2: to=<user@hostname>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.02/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
50 Jul  9 01:50:38 hostname postfix/qmgr[15890]: 8E5171208C2: removed
```

It appears there is a problem as I have a dynamicly assigned IP address from my ISP - but I don't fully understand what has gone wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of mail servers don't accept incoming connections from systems with dynamic IP addresses because most of them are systems infected with malware that tries to send spam or spread itself.

Use your ISPs mailserver as relay (sometimes called "smarthost"). [Here](http://www.postfix.org/SOHO_README.html#client_sasl_enable) is a short guide for that. The server name, user and password are the same as you'd use for a mail client like Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do, short of simply obtaining a static IP. It is Hotmail's policy to reject all mail coming from dynamic IPs.